# Jquery Icon Click

Tags: jquery, icons

I am having problem with what must be the simplest thing . A table row with a close icon in it
with the idea that I can click on the icon and delete the row.

```
<tr><td>data here</td><td><span class="clDeleteX ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></td></tr>
```

with a

```
$("#clDeleteX").click(function(ev){
    alert('icon clicked');
})
```

Can anyone dislodge the fog in my brain?

Oh yes I s'pose I should state the problem - nothing happens..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In selectors, `#` prefix is for IDs, you have to use `.` for classes.

```
$(".clDeleteX").click(function(ev){
    alert('icon clicked');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

change you code

```
$("#clDeleteX").click(function(ev){
    alert('icon clicked');
})
```

to

```
$(".clDeleteX").click(function(ev){
    alert('icon clicked');
})
```